# Xcode : Missing UI icons

Tags: xcode

Can someone explain this to me? All the icons from the xcode ui are not visible. Only selected icons are visible. For example to add a framework I need to click on the "+" sign but its hidden. Even the Apple logo in the top bar is hidden. If I navigate to another application it re-appears.

Xcode version is 6.1

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Mac

Comment: Didnt work, I'll reinstall xcode and see if this works